# How to communicate between ASP.NET and an Excel workbook

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, excel

Is there a way to load an Excel document in a web page and communicate with the excel control using code behind? (JavaScript or Asp.NET) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the excel document through the office/excel interop libraries and communicate through that way.  You could make the changes and push the Excel file to the browser.

Here is a link showing how to create an excel file using the interop assemblies:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186.aspx

Opening and manipulating excel documents through C#:
http://dotnetperls.com/excel-interop

You can't load the file in the browser and then manipulate it through asp.net if that is what you are asking.

Comment: You can display the workbook on the page using Office Web Components, I was just wondering if there was a way to communicate with it.